# migrate OpenJPA to Hibernate in spring boot 2.1.7

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, openjpa

I am migrating spring application to spring boot.spring project have JPA implemented with OpenJPA.i need to change it into hibernate.
persistance.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="PersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/queries.xml</mapping-file> 
        <class>com.dta.abc</class>  
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=ERROR, Tool=ERROR" />
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="sybase" />
            <property name="openjpa.DataCache" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

data-source.xml

```
<util:map id="sessionSettingsMap">
        <entry key="SESSION_SETTINGS_ON" value="set literal_autoparam off"/>
        <entry key="SESSION_SETTINGS_OFF" value=""/>
    </util:map>
    <bean id="sybaseDataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"  primary="true" >
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver" />     
    </bean>

    <bean id="TransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" primary="true" >
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="EntityManagerFactory" />             
    </bean>
     <bean id="openJpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.OpenJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="${connection.show_sql}" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="${connection.generateDdl}" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="${connection.dialect}" />
    </bean> 
    <bean id="EntityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" primary="true">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
         <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="openJpaVendorAdapter" /> 
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="SybaseUnit" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="javax.persistence.query.timeout">90000</prop>
            </props>
        </property>   
        <property name="packagesToScan" >
            <list>
                <value>com.datasource.jpa.dto</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

The reason for this migration is Spring Boot2.1.7 does not support OpenJPA

what are the changes need to be done for migrating OpenJPA to hibernate?.
Is there any simplest way for this?
please suggest a valid solution

**Edit 1**

```
<util:map id="sessionSettingsMap">
            <entry key="SESSION_SETTINGS_ON" value="set literal_autoparam off"/>
            <entry key="SESSION_SETTINGS_OFF" value=""/>
        </util:map>
        <bean id="sybaseDataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"  primary="true" >
            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver" />     
        </bean>

        <bean id="TransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" primary="true" >
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="EntityManagerFactory" />             
        </bean>
         <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                </bean> 
        <bean id="EntityManagerFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" primary="true">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
             <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" /> 
            <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="SybaseUnit" />
            <property name="jpaProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="javax.persistence.query.timeout">90000</prop>
                </props>
            </property>   
            <property name="packagesToScan" >
                <list>
                    <value>com.datasource.jpa.dto</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

Now it getting the error

```
.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sybaseEntityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:/C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Springboot/config/spring/dataso
e-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironmen

     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:743)
     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:390)
     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1214)
     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1203)
     at com.ge.hcit.xer.app.services.api.XERServiceMain.main(XERServiceMain.java:23)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
     at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
sed by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
     at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
     at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179)
     at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119)
     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904)
     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935)
     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
     ... 24 common frames omitted
sed by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
     ... 41 common frames omitted
```

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot and follow the proper guidelines for your `@SpringBootAPplication` annotated class and have configured the `DataSource` properly it sohould just work. Unless you are using OpenJPA specific features/annotations/...

Answer (score 0):

Im wondering why you are still using xml based configuration. You can config your Hibernate properties in application.properties file and write a configuration class to load all your beans. 
You can refer https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/hibernate-configuration-example/